# How to get thing name from MQTT topic in AWS Iot Analytics pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-analytics

I have created the following in AWS Iot Analytics:

- Channel: Iot Core topic pattern => $aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted
- Pipeline: Fed from previous channel, selects attributes from message
- Datastore to save messages

The incoming message to the channel is a shadow update/accepted and looks like this:

```
{
  "state": {
    "reported": {
      "active": false,
      "telemetry": {
        "temperature": 72,
        "humidity": 58,
        "occupancy": 28
      },
      "config": null
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "reported": {
      "active": {
        "timestamp": 1533059587
      },
      "telemetry": {
        "temperature": {
          "timestamp": 1533059587
        },
        "humidity": {
          "timestamp": 1533059587
        },
        "occupancy": {
          "timestamp": 1533059587
        }
      },
      "config": {
        "timestamp": 1533059587
      }
    }
  },
  "version": 89,
  "timestamp": 1533059587,
  "clientToken": "..."
}
```

I want to extract the thing name from the topic structure, which I have as a wild card here:

```
$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted
```

Is there any way to do this or must it be included in the message body directly if I want to use it here for processing?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are using mqtt means you can extract it via message.topic in callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is done by enriching the payload that leaves IOT Core by adding to the SQL statement in the IOT Core Rule that transmits payloads to IOT Analytics.

Comment: Current sql query is `SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'`. How can I enrich this so that the result contains the thing name? @ms-schneider-electric

Answer (score 1):

Use `topic()` function inside SQL statement:

```
SELECT *, topic() AS topic FROM 'your/thing/+/topic'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-substitution-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an accepted answer but it seems to have missed out on this part of the question which is

> I want to extract the thing name from the topic structure, which I
> have as a wild card here
>
> ```
> $aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted
> ```

I thought I'd post this for those who need to extract the thingname. If you want to extract the thing name then you can use `topic(3)` as it evaluates to 3 (which is the position of the thing name in the topic). Here is an example for a rule which republishes to a topic that uses the thingname which is retrieved from the topic.

```
{
  "sql": "SELECT state, version FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/delta'",
  "ruleDisabled": false,
  "actions": [
    {
      "republish": {
        "topic": "${topic(3)}/delta",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-iot-role"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html) to the above example. "`topic()`" returns the complete topic. These are called [Substitution templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-use-substitution-templates-in-the-rules-engine-to-enrich-iot-messages/).

Also one important thing to note (which may lead to some unnecessary debugging time) is that to republish to a reserved topic, which begins with `$`, use `$$` (escape the '$' using another '$'). For example, to republish to the device shadow topic `$aws/things/MyThing/shadow/update`, specify the topic as `$$aws/things/MyThing/shadow/update`